# Getting the value of User.Identity.Name into the model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get the User.Identity.Name value into the model that is fed to my controller action.

In my razor code I can display it

```
@User.Identity.Name
```

I have tried various methods to put that in the value of a hidden field so that it gets submitted with the model.

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.UserName, new {@value=User.Identity.Name })
```

My view model:

```
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
```

Is there a better or proper way to do this?

Ultimately I will log this data into a logging database on the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to display it on the client and send it up. In your controller you can simply do:

```
User.Identity.Name
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably do not want to have this value coming from the client, as it can be changed to anything they want.

Instead, you would want the action method that receives the submitted form to set this value from User.Identity.Name

```
myModel.UserName  = User.Identity.Name
```